# Weird behavior of `Quantile` function

Tags: numerical-integration, probability-or-statistics

I found a very strange behavior of `Quantile` function when evaluating the following expression:

```
Quantile[TruncatedDistribution[{0, \[Infinity]}, 
  MixtureDistribution[{0.5, 
    0.5}, {NormalDistribution[30.0505043478260844836, 
     1.6756943154326708889], 
    NormalDistribution[30.0505043478260844836, 
     2.8804367798735217576]}]], 0.5]
```

Mathematica was freezing after I hit `shift+enter`, and there seems to be an infinite loop inside because it kept freezing for a couple of hours.

However, if I change the quantile from `0.5` to `0.500001` it gives me the result immediately.

Or if I remove some digits, e.g., the following:

```
Quantile[TruncatedDistribution[{0, \[Infinity]}, 
  MixtureDistribution[{0.5, 
    0.5}, {NormalDistribution[30.0505043478260844836, 1.6756], 
    NormalDistribution[30.0505043478260844836, 
     2.8804367798735217576]}]], 0.5]
```

(note the 1.6756 v.s. 1.6756943154326708889) gives me the result almost immediately as well.

This is so weird as I don't see any fundamental differences between these numbers. It should always gives the results immediately.

Is this a BUG or there are some tricky things within these numbers?

### System versions:

OS: macOS Catalina 10.15

Mathematica: 12.0.0.0

Comment: Works fine in original form on windows 10, MMA 12, returns result in a few milliseconds.

Comment: @ciao Yea, I guess it should be some system/version specific bug.

Answer (score 1):

With macOS Catalina 10.15

```
$Version

(* "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)
```

The precision of your distribution is only machine precision due to the presence of low precision numbers; specifically, `0.5`

```
dist1 = TruncatedDistribution[{0, ∞},
   MixtureDistribution[{0.5, 0.5}, {
     NormalDistribution[30.0505043478260844836,
      1.6756943154326708889],
     NormalDistribution[30.0505043478260844836,
      2.8804367798735217576]}]];

Precision@dist1

(* MachinePrecision *)
```

Use arbitrary-precision rather than machine precision

```
dist2 = TruncatedDistribution[{0, ∞},
    MixtureDistribution[{0.5, 0.5}, {
      NormalDistribution[30.0505043478260844836,
       1.6756943154326708889],
      NormalDistribution[30.0505043478260844836,
       2.8804367798735217576]}]] //
   SetPrecision[#, 20] &;

(q = Quantile[dist2, SetPrecision[0.5, #]] & /@ 
    Range[5, 20, 5]) // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.031084, {30.1, 30.050504, 30.05050434783, 30.0505043478260845}} *)
```

The complicated nature of the distribution results in loss of precision from the input precision.

```
Precision /@ q

(* {2.92646, 7.60064, 12.5271, 17.5271} *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your information! Now I know it is caused by the precision differences. However, what is the root cause for the extreme long timing when using `MachinePrecision`? And why it only happens to these specific numbers? Actually, if you try: ```dist1 = TruncatedDistribution[{0, ∞},
   MixtureDistribution[{0.5, 0.5}, {
     NormalDistribution[30.0505043478260844836,
      2.6756943154326708889],
     NormalDistribution[30.0505043478260844836,
      2.8804367798735217576]}]];``` Note the `1.67xxx` v.s. `2.67xxx`. It also gives me the result in 6ms.